# Using regular expressions in express application with router middleware

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I am trying to use a regex pattern instead of a string in the app.use statement that sets up my Router middleware for a path.  Why would this not work?

```
var express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var router = express.Router();
app.use(/\/regexPath/, router);
```

But this does?

```
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/regexPath', router);
```

The only problem with using the 2nd one is it accepts all mixes of upper and lowercase.  Using the reg exp forces it to lowercase which is what we want.  The "case sensitive routing" option in Express 4 does not appear to work as nothing changes.

I know the regex works as it did in another application.  I am stuck as to why doing the same thing in a different server would give me this error.

```
Router.use() requires callback functions but got a [object RegExp]
```

Edit - The following works.
app.js:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    // master process
    var cpus = require('os').cpus().length;
    console.log('Master process: num CPUs='+cpus);
    for(var i=0; i < cpus; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    // Listen for dying workers
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
        // Replace the dead worker, we're not sentimental
        console.log('Worker '+worker.id+' died :(');
        cluster.fork();
    });
} //end master process

else {
    // child instances
    var express = require("express"),
        app = express();
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
    require('./routes')(app);
    app.listen(8666);
} //end worker process
```

routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    // weather app
    var weather = require('./handlers/weather');
    app.get(/\/weather/, weather.findAll);
    app.get(/\/weather\/:id/, weather.findById);
    app.post(/\/weather/, weather.add);
    app.put(/\/weather\/:id/, weather.update);
    app.delete(/\/weather\/:id/, weather.delete);

    // image proxies
    app.get(/\/radar\/local/, weather.localRadar);
    app.get(/\/radar\/regional/, weather.regionalRadar);
    app.get(/\/radar\/satellite/, weather.satellite);
    app.get(/\/radar\/map/, weather.map);

    // blood pressure app
    var bp = require('./handlers/bp');
    app.get(/\/BP/, bp.findAll);
    app.get(/\/BP\/:id/, bp.findById);
    app.post(/\/BP/, bp.add);
    app.put(/\/BP\/:id/, bp.update);
    app.delete(/\/BP\/:id/, bp.delete);

    // nutrition app
    var nutrition = require('./handlers/nutrition');
    app.get(/\/nutrition/, nutrition.findAll);
    app.get(/\/nutrition\/:id/, nutrition.findById);
    app.post(/\/nutrition/, nutrition.add);
    app.put(/\/nutrition\/:id/, nutrition.update);
    app.delete(/\/nutrition\/:id/, nutrition.delete);
};
```

So I really don't know what is different that allows this to work and the first one in my post to not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what doesn't make sense is it works in another server app using the Router instance in place of the callback function, which the docs say I should be able to do.

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the working server's code.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Which version of Express are you using?

Comment: Currently using Express 4.0.0 and it is the same machine and node install that works in the 2nd example above.  So why does the first sample fail?

Comment: In your working Code your are not using `app.use`with an regex, and what is confusing, is that your are setting the `app.use`, and the error says `... Router.use() ...`, can you post the whole code? Is the `app` var really an Express object?

Comment: Yes, app is an express object.  Will add to the original post.

Comment: thanks for the Update, I tried some clean express installations Version 3.x and Version 4.x, and test Programms, but it works with 4.x. I'm Sorry I can't reproduce it. Maybe a clean installation could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a older Version of Express upgrade to Version 4, than it should work.

here is the Api for app.use()  Express 3.X [Documentation](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.use)

> A route will match any path, which follows its path immediately with either a “/” or a “.”. For example: app.use('/apple', ...) will match /apple, /apple/images, /apple/images/news, /apple.html, /apple.html.txt, and so on.

and here for Expres 4.X [Documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use)

> path can be a string representing a path, a path pattern, a regular expression to match paths, or an array of combinations thereof.

Comment: I am already using version 4.  From the package.json in the express node_module:    "name": "express",
    "description": "Sinatra inspired web development framework",
    "version": "4.0.0",